# How to Run Plot Study for a Dynamic Number of Symbols Using Array and For Loop in Pinescript Tradinview?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have created the following study, however I want to run it through a variable number of symbols using for loop and arrays.

```
//@version=5
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © ebfsantos

indicator(title='Multi Squeeze for Power Plays', shorttitle='Multi-SQZ', overlay=false)

n = input(10,"Number of Symbols")
length = input(20,"Length")


//RUN FROM HERE ON INSIDE A FOR LOOP USING ARRAY. 

//for counter = 1 to N


symb1 = input.symbol("XLK", "Symbol 1")
symb2 = input.symbol("SMH", "Symbol 2")
symb3 = input.symbol("XLV", "Symbol 3")
symb4 = input.symbol("XLF", "Symbol 4")
symb5 = input.symbol("XLC", "Symbol 5")
symb6 = input.symbol("NVDA", "Symbol 6")
symb7 = input.symbol("AAPL", "Symbol 7")
symb8 = input.symbol("MSFT", "Symbol 8")
.
.
.
symbN = input.symbol("MSFT", "Symbol N")


symb1c = request.security(symb1, timeframe.period, close)

source1 = symb1c

ma = ta.sma(source1, length)

devBB = ta.stdev(source1, length)
devKC = request.security(symb1, timeframe.period, ta.sma(ta.tr, length))

//Bollinger 2x
upBB = ma + devBB * 2
lowBB = ma - devBB * 2

//Keltner 2x
upKCWide = ma + devKC * 2
lowKCWide = ma - devKC * 2

//Keltner 1.5x
upKCNormal = ma + devKC * 1.5
lowKCNormal = ma - devKC * 1.5

//Keltner 1x
upKCNarrow = ma + devKC
lowKCNarrow = ma - devKC

sqzOnWide = lowBB >= lowKCWide and upBB <= upKCWide  //WIDE SQUEEZE: BLACK
sqzOnNormal = lowBB >= lowKCNormal and upBB <= upKCNormal  //NORMAL SQUEEZE: RED
sqzOnNarrow = lowBB >= lowKCNarrow and upBB <= upKCNarrow  //NARROW SQUEEZE: ORANGE
sqzOffWide = lowBB < lowKCWide and upBB > upKCWide  //FIRED WIDE SQUEEZE: GREEN
noSqz = sqzOnWide == false and sqzOffWide == false  //NO SQUEEZE: BLUE

//Squeeze Dots color
color_1 = color.new(#ffffff,0)
color_2 = color.new(#27c5fd,0)
color_3 = color.new(#0c5974,0)
color_4 = color.new(#1a233c,90)

sq_color = noSqz ? color.blue : sqzOnNarrow ? color_1 : sqzOnNormal ? color_2 : sqzOnWide ? color_3 : color_4

p1 = plot(1, title='SQZ', color=sq_color, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)
```

I have it working for one symbol, and I would like to have it for a dynamic number of symbols using arrays and for loop. My coding skills are limited and would appreciate the help in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have separate inputs for every symbol you want to use. There is no way to dynamically change the settings tab with an input. However, you can control the array size with that input, which will in turn determine how many symbols you are scanning at a time.

You can create a function that calculates all of the squeezes, in my example I only did the wide squeezes. You will be able to get the others with the framework. I just put the results into a table for demonstration.

```
indicator(title='Multi Squeeze for Power Plays', shorttitle='Multi-SQZ', overlay=true)

n = input(8,"Number of Symbols")
length = input(20,"Length")

symb1 = input.symbol("XLK", "Symbol 1"),
symb2 = input.symbol("SMH", "Symbol 2")
symb3 = input.symbol("XLV", "Symbol 3")
symb4 = input.symbol("XLF", "Symbol 4")
symb5 = input.symbol("XLC", "Symbol 5")
symb6 = input.symbol("NVDA", "Symbol 6")
symb7 = input.symbol("AAPL", "Symbol 7")
symb8 = input.symbol("MSFT", "Symbol 8")

symbArr = array.from(symb1,symb2,symb3,symb4,symb5,symb6,symb7,symb8)
var table sqTab = table.new(position.top_right, 2,10)
symArr = array.new<string>()
sqArr = array.new<bool>()

fsplit(a)=>
    sym  = str.split(a, ":")

getData(sym)=>
    [ma,devbb,devkc] = request.security(sym, timeframe.period, [ta.sma(close,length),ta.stdev(close,length),ta.sma(ta.tr,length)])
    upBB = ma + devbb * 2
    lowBB = ma - devbb * 2
    upKCWide = ma + devkc * 2
    lowKCWide = ma - devkc * 2
    sqWide = lowBB >= lowKCWide and upBB <= upKCWide
    sqWide

sqArr.unshift(getData(symb1))
sqArr.unshift(getData(symb2))
sqArr.unshift(getData(symb3))
sqArr.unshift(getData(symb4))
sqArr.unshift(getData(symb5))
sqArr.unshift(getData(symb6))
sqArr.unshift(getData(symb7))
sqArr.unshift(getData(symb8))

if barstate.islast
    for s in symbArr
        if symArr.size() < n
            symArr.unshift(fsplit(s).get(1))
    for i = 0 to symArr.size()-1
        sqTab.cell(0,i, symArr.get(i), text_color = color.black)
        sqTab.cell(1,i, str.tostring(sqArr.get(i)), text_color = color.black)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input @AmphibianTrading. I will work through it trying to plot the wide squeeze and provide feedback. I much appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

He is the complete study not using array and and for loop. I will continue trying to use array and loop so it can be easier to change the number of symbols.

```
//@version=5
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © ebfsantos

indicator(title='Multi Squeeze for Power Plays', shorttitle='Multi-SQZ', overlay=false)

n = input(8,"Number of Symbols")
length = input(20,"Length")
labeloffset=input(4,"Ticker Offset")

//for counter = 1 to n
symb1 = input.symbol("XLK", "Symbol 1")
symb2 = input.symbol("XLY", "Symbol 2")
symb3 = input.symbol("SMH", "Symbol 3")
symb4 = input.symbol("XLU", "Symbol 4")
symb5 = input.symbol("XLV", "Symbol 5")
symb6 = input.symbol("XLP", "Symbol 6")
symb7 = input.symbol("XLF", "Symbol 7")
symb8 = input.symbol("XLC", "Symbol 8")

symb1c = request.security(symb1, timeframe.period, close)
symb2c = request.security(symb2, timeframe.period, close)
symb3c = request.security(symb3, timeframe.period, close)
symb4c = request.security(symb4, timeframe.period, close)
symb5c = request.security(symb5, timeframe.period, close)
symb6c = request.security(symb6, timeframe.period, close)
symb7c = request.security(symb7, timeframe.period, close)
symb8c = request.security(symb8, timeframe.period, close)

source1 = symb1c
source2 = symb2c
source3 = symb3c
source4 = symb4c
source5 = symb5c
source6 = symb6c
source7 = symb7c
source8 = symb8c

ma1 = ta.sma(source1, length)
ma2 = ta.sma(source2, length)
ma3 = ta.sma(source3, length)
ma4 = ta.sma(source4, length)
ma5 = ta.sma(source5, length)
ma6 = ta.sma(source6, length)
ma7 = ta.sma(source7, length)
ma8 = ta.sma(source8, length)

devBB1 = ta.stdev(source1,length)
devBB2 = ta.stdev(source2,length)
devBB3 = ta.stdev(source3,length)
devBB4 = ta.stdev(source4,length)
devBB5 = ta.stdev(source5,length)
devBB6 = ta.stdev(source6,length)
devBB7 = ta.stdev(source7,length)
devBB8 = ta.stdev(source8,length)

devKC1 = request.security(symb1, timeframe.period, ta.sma(ta.tr,length))
devKC2 = request.security(symb2, timeframe.period, ta.sma(ta.tr,length))
devKC3 = request.security(symb3, timeframe.period, ta.sma(ta.tr,length))
devKC4 = request.security(symb4, timeframe.period, ta.sma(ta.tr,length))
devKC5 = request.security(symb5, timeframe.period, ta.sma(ta.tr,length))
devKC6 = request.security(symb6, timeframe.period, ta.sma(ta.tr,length))
devKC7 = request.security(symb7, timeframe.period, ta.sma(ta.tr,length))
devKC8 = request.security(symb8, timeframe.period, ta.sma(ta.tr,length))

//Bollinger 2x
upBB1 = ma1 + devBB1 * 2
upBB2 = ma2 + devBB2 * 2
upBB3 = ma3 + devBB3 * 2
upBB4 = ma4 + devBB4 * 2
upBB5 = ma5 + devBB5 * 2
upBB6 = ma6 + devBB6 * 2
upBB7 = ma7 + devBB7 * 2
upBB8 = ma8 + devBB8 * 2

lowBB1 = ma1 - devBB1 * 2
lowBB2 = ma2 - devBB2 * 2
lowBB3 = ma3 - devBB3 * 2
lowBB4 = ma4 - devBB4 * 2
lowBB5 = ma5 - devBB5 * 2
lowBB6 = ma6 - devBB6 * 2
lowBB7 = ma7 - devBB7 * 2
lowBB8 = ma8 - devBB8 * 2

//Keltner 2x
upKCWide1 = ma1 + devKC1 * 2
upKCWide2 = ma2 + devKC2 * 2
upKCWide3 = ma3 + devKC3 * 2
upKCWide4 = ma4 + devKC4 * 2
upKCWide5 = ma5 + devKC5 * 2
upKCWide6 = ma6 + devKC6 * 2
upKCWide7 = ma7 + devKC7 * 2
upKCWide8 = ma8 + devKC8 * 2

lowKCWide1 = ma1 - devKC1 * 2
lowKCWide2 = ma2 - devKC2 * 2
lowKCWide3 = ma3 - devKC3 * 2
lowKCWide4 = ma4 - devKC4 * 2
lowKCWide5 = ma5 - devKC5 * 2
lowKCWide6 = ma6 - devKC6 * 2
lowKCWide7 = ma7 - devKC7 * 2
lowKCWide8 = ma8 - devKC8 * 2

//Keltner 1.5x
upKCNormal1 = ma1 + devKC1 * 1.5
upKCNormal2 = ma2 + devKC2 * 1.5
upKCNormal3 = ma3 + devKC3 * 1.5
upKCNormal4 = ma4 + devKC4 * 1.5
upKCNormal5 = ma5 + devKC5 * 1.5
upKCNormal6 = ma6 + devKC6 * 1.5
upKCNormal7 = ma7 + devKC7 * 1.5
upKCNormal8 = ma8 + devKC8 * 1.5

lowKCNormal1 = ma1 - devKC1 * 1.5
lowKCNormal2 = ma2 - devKC2 * 1.5
lowKCNormal3 = ma3 - devKC3 * 1.5
lowKCNormal4 = ma4 - devKC4 * 1.5
lowKCNormal5 = ma5 - devKC5 * 1.5
lowKCNormal6 = ma6 - devKC6 * 1.5
lowKCNormal7 = ma7 - devKC7 * 1.5
lowKCNormal8 = ma8 - devKC8 * 1.5

//Keltner 1x
upKCNarrow1 = ma1 + devKC1
upKCNarrow2 = ma2 + devKC2
upKCNarrow3 = ma3 + devKC3
upKCNarrow4 = ma4 + devKC4
upKCNarrow5 = ma5 + devKC5
upKCNarrow6 = ma6 + devKC6
upKCNarrow7 = ma7 + devKC7
upKCNarrow8 = ma8 + devKC8

lowKCNarrow1 = ma1 - devKC1
lowKCNarrow2 = ma2 - devKC2
lowKCNarrow3 = ma3 - devKC3
lowKCNarrow4 = ma4 - devKC4
lowKCNarrow5 = ma5 - devKC5
lowKCNarrow6 = ma6 - devKC6
lowKCNarrow7 = ma7 - devKC7
lowKCNarrow8 = ma8 - devKC8

sqzOnWide1 = lowBB1 >= lowKCWide1 and upBB1 <= upKCWide1  //WIDE SQUEEZE: BLACK
sqzOnWide2 = lowBB2 >= lowKCWide2 and upBB2 <= upKCWide2  //WIDE SQUEEZE: BLACK
sqzOnWide3 = lowBB3 >= lowKCWide3 and upBB3 <= upKCWide3  //WIDE SQUEEZE: BLACK
sqzOnWide4 = lowBB4 >= lowKCWide4 and upBB4 <= upKCWide4  //WIDE SQUEEZE: BLACK
sqzOnWide5 = lowBB5 >= lowKCWide5 and upBB5 <= upKCWide5  //WIDE SQUEEZE: BLACK
sqzOnWide6 = lowBB6 >= lowKCWide6 and upBB6 <= upKCWide6  //WIDE SQUEEZE: BLACK
sqzOnWide7 = lowBB7 >= lowKCWide7 and upBB7 <= upKCWide7  //WIDE SQUEEZE: BLACK
sqzOnWide8 = lowBB8 >= lowKCWide8 and upBB8 <= upKCWide8  //WIDE SQUEEZE: BLACK

sqzOnNormal1 = lowBB1 >= lowKCNormal1 and upBB1 <= upKCNormal1  //NORMAL SQUEEZE: RED
sqzOnNormal2 = lowBB2 >= lowKCNormal2 and upBB2 <= upKCNormal2  //NORMAL SQUEEZE: RED
sqzOnNormal3 = lowBB3 >= lowKCNormal3 and upBB3 <= upKCNormal3  //NORMAL SQUEEZE: RED
sqzOnNormal4 = lowBB4 >= lowKCNormal4 and upBB4 <= upKCNormal4  //NORMAL SQUEEZE: RED
sqzOnNormal5 = lowBB5 >= lowKCNormal5 and upBB5 <= upKCNormal5  //NORMAL SQUEEZE: RED
sqzOnNormal6 = lowBB6 >= lowKCNormal6 and upBB6 <= upKCNormal6  //NORMAL SQUEEZE: RED
sqzOnNormal7 = lowBB7 >= lowKCNormal7 and upBB7 <= upKCNormal7  //NORMAL SQUEEZE: RED
sqzOnNormal8 = lowBB8 >= lowKCNormal8 and upBB8 <= upKCNormal8  //NORMAL SQUEEZE: RED

sqzOnNarrow1 = lowBB1 >= lowKCNarrow1 and upBB1 <= upKCNarrow1  //NARROW SQUEEZE: ORANGE
sqzOnNarrow2 = lowBB2 >= lowKCNarrow2 and upBB2 <= upKCNarrow2  //NARROW SQUEEZE: ORANGE
sqzOnNarrow3 = lowBB3 >= lowKCNarrow3 and upBB3 <= upKCNarrow3  //NARROW SQUEEZE: ORANGE
sqzOnNarrow4 = lowBB4 >= lowKCNarrow4 and upBB4 <= upKCNarrow4  //NARROW SQUEEZE: ORANGE
sqzOnNarrow5 = lowBB5 >= lowKCNarrow5 and upBB5 <= upKCNarrow5  //NARROW SQUEEZE: ORANGE
sqzOnNarrow6 = lowBB6 >= lowKCNarrow6 and upBB6 <= upKCNarrow6  //NARROW SQUEEZE: ORANGE
sqzOnNarrow7 = lowBB7 >= lowKCNarrow7 and upBB7 <= upKCNarrow7  //NARROW SQUEEZE: ORANGE
sqzOnNarrow8 = lowBB8 >= lowKCNarrow8 and upBB8 <= upKCNarrow8  //NARROW SQUEEZE: ORANGE

sqzOffWide1 = lowBB1 < lowKCWide1 and upBB1 > upKCWide1  //FIRED WIDE SQUEEZE: GREEN
sqzOffWide2 = lowBB2 < lowKCWide2 and upBB2 > upKCWide2  //FIRED WIDE SQUEEZE: GREEN
sqzOffWide3 = lowBB3 < lowKCWide3 and upBB3 > upKCWide3  //FIRED WIDE SQUEEZE: GREEN
sqzOffWide4 = lowBB4 < lowKCWide4 and upBB4 > upKCWide4  //FIRED WIDE SQUEEZE: GREEN
sqzOffWide5 = lowBB5 < lowKCWide5 and upBB5 > upKCWide5  //FIRED WIDE SQUEEZE: GREEN
sqzOffWide6 = lowBB6 < lowKCWide6 and upBB6 > upKCWide6  //FIRED WIDE SQUEEZE: GREEN
sqzOffWide7 = lowBB7 < lowKCWide7 and upBB7 > upKCWide7  //FIRED WIDE SQUEEZE: GREEN
sqzOffWide8 = lowBB8 < lowKCWide8 and upBB8 > upKCWide8  //FIRED WIDE SQUEEZE: GREEN

noSqz1 = sqzOnWide1 == false and sqzOffWide1 == false  //NO SQUEEZE: BLUE
noSqz2 = sqzOnWide2 == false and sqzOffWide2 == false  //NO SQUEEZE: BLUE
noSqz3 = sqzOnWide3 == false and sqzOffWide3 == false  //NO SQUEEZE: BLUE
noSqz4 = sqzOnWide4 == false and sqzOffWide4 == false  //NO SQUEEZE: BLUE
noSqz5 = sqzOnWide5 == false and sqzOffWide5 == false  //NO SQUEEZE: BLUE
noSqz6 = sqzOnWide6 == false and sqzOffWide6 == false  //NO SQUEEZE: BLUE
noSqz7 = sqzOnWide7 == false and sqzOffWide7 == false  //NO SQUEEZE: BLUE
noSqz8 = sqzOnWide8 == false and sqzOffWide8 == false  //NO SQUEEZE: BLUE

//Squeeze Dots color
color_1 = color.new(#ffffff,0)
color_2 = color.new(#27c5fd,0)
color_3 = color.new(#0c5974,0)
color_4 = color.new(#1a233c,50)

sq_color1 = noSqz1 ? color.blue : sqzOnNarrow1 ? color_1 : sqzOnNormal1 ? color_2 : sqzOnWide1 ? color_3 : color_4
sq_color2 = noSqz2 ? color.blue : sqzOnNarrow2 ? color_1 : sqzOnNormal2 ? color_2 : sqzOnWide2 ? color_3 : color_4
sq_color3 = noSqz3 ? color.blue : sqzOnNarrow3 ? color_1 : sqzOnNormal3 ? color_2 : sqzOnWide3 ? color_3 : color_4
sq_color4 = noSqz4 ? color.blue : sqzOnNarrow4 ? color_1 : sqzOnNormal4 ? color_2 : sqzOnWide4 ? color_3 : color_4
sq_color5 = noSqz5 ? color.blue : sqzOnNarrow5 ? color_1 : sqzOnNormal5 ? color_2 : sqzOnWide5 ? color_3 : color_4
sq_color6 = noSqz6 ? color.blue : sqzOnNarrow6 ? color_1 : sqzOnNormal6 ? color_2 : sqzOnWide6 ? color_3 : color_4
sq_color7 = noSqz7 ? color.blue : sqzOnNarrow7 ? color_1 : sqzOnNormal7 ? color_2 : sqzOnWide7 ? color_3 : color_4
sq_color8 = noSqz8 ? color.blue : sqzOnNarrow8 ? color_1 : sqzOnNormal8 ? color_2 : sqzOnWide8 ? color_3 : color_4

p1 = plot(n-1, title="SQZ", color=sq_color1, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)
p2 = plot(n-2, title='SQZ', color=sq_color2, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)
p3 = plot(n-3, title='SQZ', color=sq_color3, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)
p4 = plot(n-4, title='SQZ', color=sq_color4, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)
p5 = plot(n-5, title='SQZ', color=sq_color5, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)
p6 = plot(n-6, title='SQZ', color=sq_color6, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)
p7 = plot(n-7, title='SQZ', color=sq_color7, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)
p8 = plot(n-8, title='SQZ', color=sq_color8, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)

pos1 = str.pos(symb1,":")  // Get position of ":" character
pos2 = str.pos(symb2,":")  // Get position of ":" character
pos3 = str.pos(symb3,":")  // Get position of ":" character
pos4 = str.pos(symb4,":")  // Get position of ":" character
pos5 = str.pos(symb5,":")  // Get position of ":" character
pos6 = str.pos(symb6,":")  // Get position of ":" character
pos7 = str.pos(symb7,":")  // Get position of ":" character
pos8 = str.pos(symb8,":")  // Get position of ":" character

tkr1= str.substring(symb1, pos1+1) // "Extract strings after ':' "
tkr2= str.substring(symb2, pos2+1) // "Extract strings after ':' "
tkr3= str.substring(symb3, pos3+1) // "Extract strings after ':' "
tkr4= str.substring(symb4, pos4+1) // "Extract strings after ':' "
tkr5= str.substring(symb5, pos5+1) // "Extract strings after ':' "
tkr6= str.substring(symb6, pos6+1) // "Extract strings after ':' "
tkr7= str.substring(symb7, pos7+1) // "Extract strings after ':' "
tkr8= str.substring(symb8, pos8+1) // "Extract strings after ':' "


l1 = label.new(bar_index[0]+labeloffset, n-1, tkr1,style=label.style_text_outline,textalign=text.align_right,textcolor=#27c5fd,color=#131722)
l2 = label.new(bar_index[0]+labeloffset, n-2, tkr2,style=label.style_text_outline,textalign=text.align_right,textcolor=#27c5fd,color=#131722)
l3 = label.new(bar_index[0]+labeloffset, n-3, tkr3,style=label.style_text_outline,textalign=text.align_right,textcolor=#27c5fd,color=#131722)
l4 = label.new(bar_index[0]+labeloffset, n-4, tkr4,style=label.style_text_outline,textalign=text.align_right,textcolor=#27c5fd,color=#131722)
l5 = label.new(bar_index[0]+labeloffset, n-5, tkr5,style=label.style_text_outline,textalign=text.align_right,textcolor=#27c5fd,color=#131722)
l6 = label.new(bar_index[0]+labeloffset, n-6, tkr6,style=label.style_text_outline,textalign=text.align_right,textcolor=#27c5fd,color=#131722)
l7 = label.new(bar_index[0]+labeloffset, n-7, tkr7,style=label.style_text_outline,textalign=text.align_right,textcolor=#27c5fd,color=#131722)
l8 = label.new(bar_index[0]+labeloffset, n-8, tkr8,style=label.style_text_outline,textalign=text.align_right,textcolor=#27c5fd,color=#131722)

label.delete(l1[1])
label.delete(l2[1])
label.delete(l3[1])
label.delete(l4[1])
label.delete(l5[1])
label.delete(l6[1])
label.delete(l7[1])
label.delete(l8[1])
```

I understand what @AmphibianTrading mentioned that there is no way to dynamically change the settings tab with an input. I was thinking however of in the code changing "n" and with that create "n" symb'n' inputs.

I hope this can be useful to someone, and that someone can help with putting into an array and loop.

Comment: You won’t be able to change the number of inputs with a setting. You can only control how many of the inputs (symbols) get passed into your array